# What is the equivalent NSBox from AppKit to be used in Cocoa Touch environment?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, appkit

Is there a similar to NSBox class from AppKit for MAC in UIKit for iPad?

Comment: Would help if you described what configuration of an `NSBox` you're talking about, since it could be anything from a titled frame (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Box/Tasks/SettingBoxAppear.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000081-BAJEAIEE) to a simple line separator: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Box/Tasks/UsingToCreateVisualSep.html

Comment: I have chosen UIView to replace it.  I was using NSBox to contain other user controls such as button, checkbox, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You will have to customize a UIView, but its not that hard. You can easily make a UIView that looks completely identical, and the best part is that when you remove the uiview, all the containing items inside it are removed.

in effect, all items (like uibutton and uiscrollview) are actually children of UIview.

Comment: I was thinking the same.  I do a test with UIView and it performs the tasks that I have been used previously in NSBox.

Comment: When it moves, it contents move. When it hides, the contents hides. The alpha is stacked in one layer, making semi-transparency decent to watch, and hell... its the mother of all UI elements :] Best of luck with your project.